# What is the minimum mass for an object to exert a gravitational force over a smaller object?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Example: due to the earths size it exerts a gravitational force on a car, if in an isolated environment with no other objects, would a bowling ball exert a gravitational force over a piece of dust? Or a similar object sizes, let's say, earth to car ratio

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_universal_gravitation

Comment: The car also exerts a gravitational force on the Earth. And the speck of dust exerts a gravitational force on the bowling ball.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum mass is zero. The tiniest amount of mass exerts gravitational force, and even massless particles like photons exert gravitational force because they have energy and momentum. Furthermore, objects don't exert force only on smaller objects; they exert force on larger objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

The force that an object acts on another is $\frac{GMm}{r^2}$.  As such, as long as the masses are non-zero, there is a force exerted.